# Scala programming mystery

Tags: scala

I was expecting below program to print each character of the String "This is a test" on a seperate line , However when i run this snippet on scalafiddle.io , It does not print anything , Can you please help me to find why ?

```
    abstract class AbsIterator{
      type T
      def hasNext:Boolean
      def next():T
    }

    class StringIterator(s:String) extends AbsIterator{
      type T = Char
      private var i = 0
      def hasNext = i < s.length

      def next()={
        val ch = s charAt i
        i += 1
        ch
      }
    }

    trait RichIterator extends AbsIterator{
        def foreach (f:T => Unit):Unit = while(hasNext) f(next())
      }

    object StringIteratorTest extends App{
     class Iter extends StringIterator ("This is a test") with RichIterator
      val iter = new Iter
      iter foreach println
    }
```

Comment: It compiles and runs fine for me without any modifications.

Comment: @jwvh , I tried running it in scalafiddle.io as well as the intellij scala scratch , Both do not print any values , Can you please tell me what did you use to run this code.

Comment: Very simple. 1-I copied the text to a file: `vi so.sc` 2-I compiled the code: `scalac -Xlint so.sc` 3-I ran the program: `scala StringIteratorTest` The output is just as you've described it.

Comment: It also runs in an IntelliJ worksheet by adding this line at the end of the code: `StringIteratorTest.main(Array[String]())` (This is outside of the `StringIteratorTest` object code.)

Comment: It also runs as a straight script, `scala -nc runit.sc`, though it doesn't work in Ammonite, `amm runit.sc`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you said you tried on scalafiddle, its not executing anything inside main method.

```
println("as a script - will be executed")

object x extends App  {
  println("as main app - will not be executed")
}
```

you probably need to run it as a script as below, working scalafiddle code here - https://scalafiddle.io/sf/3CzSXSp/0

```
abstract class AbsIterator{
  type T
  def hasNext:Boolean
  def next():T
}

class StringIterator(s:String) extends AbsIterator{
  type T = Char
  private var i = 0
  def hasNext = i < s.length

  def next(): T = {
    val ch = s charAt i
    i += 1
    ch
  }
}

trait RichIterator extends AbsIterator{
  def foreach (f:T => Unit):Unit = while(hasNext) f(next())
}

class Iter extends StringIterator ("This is a test") with RichIterator
val iter = new Iter
iter foreach println
```

### output

```
T
h
i
s

i
s

a

t
e
s
t
```

code - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/prayagupd/UPw6pIqtRPeNlXOr4wDlSw

Comment: Adding the return type to next() does not help , In fact I had taken this snippet from the scala documentation site and they don't specify the explicit return type to next method as well.

Comment: @mprad Actually its working without return type too, can you check the runnign code over here - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/prayagupd/UPw6pIqtRPeNlXOr4wDlSw

Comment: @mprad did you try stripping out the main method in scala fiddle, scalafiddle does not execute anything inside `main`, you have to flatten the code you want to execute. see example https://scalafiddle.io/sf/Obysqtp/1

Comment: for pointing to the working scalafiddle and also for the scastie , it seems to be cool.

Answer (score 0):

`App` is supposed to be used as a command-line "main" application. 
When you compile it, and run on command line, JVM finds and executes `main` method, defined in the `App`, that executes the code you put into the body of the object. Scala also uses some black magic to prevent the object's body from being executed before `main` is called.

`scalafiddle.io` does not do that. It simply executes the code you type there. So, the problem is that you defined the constructor for `StringIteratorTest`, but never executed it.

If you ran this as a command line application, scala would have done it for you, but on scalafiddle (and other repl-like tools), you have to invoke it explicitly. Adding this line to the end of your script makes it happen:
`StringIteratorTest.main(Array.empty[String])`

Answer (score 0):

I think scalafiddle doesn't run your `App`. Try script mode:

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/3GTzp41/1

```
abstract class AbsIterator {
  type T
  def hasNext:Boolean
  def next():T
}

class StringIterator(s:String) extends AbsIterator {
  type T = Char
  private var i = 0
  def hasNext = i < s.length

  def next()={
    val ch = s charAt i
    i += 1
    ch
  }
}

trait RichIterator extends AbsIterator {
  def foreach (f:T => Unit):Unit = while(hasNext) f(next())
}

class Iter extends StringIterator ("This is a test") with RichIterator

val iter = new Iter
iter foreach println
```